# Compilation error with gfortran and mpif90

Tags: mpi, gfortran, openmpi

I am trying to compile and run this software. I have `Open-MPI` library installed with `gfortran`. I get the following error.

```
mpif90 -o .obj/mod4source.o mod4source.f90 -g -heap-arrays -fcheck=all -traceback -ftree-vectorize -fbounds-check -O2  -w -lm -c -funroll-loops -J.mod -I/home/guddu/includess 
gfortran: error: unrecognized command-line option '-h'
gfortran: error: unrecognized command-line option '-traceback'
make: *** [.obj/mod4source.o] Error 1

mpif90 --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

It is unclear to me where the error is coming from. `-h` is not even in the compilation flags in the command. I have a feeling it is somehow related to these two issues ([Compiler doesn't recognize flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507835/compiler-doesnt-recognize-flags), [gfortran is called instead of mpif90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335519/gfortran-is-called-instead-of-mpif90)) but I can't connect the dots. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Neither -heap-arrays nor -traceback are gfortran flags (they are Intel flags). Why do you use them? What is *"this software"*?

Comment: thanks very much for point out those flags are only for the Intel compiler. I removed them and the code compiles now, lets see if the software runs correctly. It is a code written by my colleague and I am trying to run it. It is not public.